# Como calcular a data e o código do turno?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Tenho uma tabela que especifica a hora inicial de um turno de trabalho e sua duração em minutos:

```
codigo      descricao           inicio(datetime)        duracao(int)
S01         PRIMEIRO            1900-01-01 05:00:00.000 540
S02         SEGUNDO             1900-01-01 14:00:00.000 540
S03         TERCEIRO            1900-01-01 23:00:00.000 360
```

Tenho também uma tabela de lançamentos, que possui a data e hora do lançamento:

```
serie       hora
743         2016-06-24 23:06:19.663
744         2016-06-25 00:05:17.852
745         2016-06-25 08:01:27.001
746         2016-06-25 16:08:01.923
```

Preciso classificar os lançamentos baseados na tabela de turnos, de forma que possa obter uma saída da seguinte forma:

```
serie       dia        codigo
743         2016-06-24 S03
744         2016-06-24 S03
745         2016-06-25 S01
746         2016-06-25 S02
```

Pois o turno correspondente compreende o período de tempo entre seu início e seu final, que é a soma da duração com o horário inicial. Dessa forma, lançamentos feitos entre 23:00:00 e 04:59:59 pertencem ao turno S03, entre 05:00:00 e 13:59:59 pertencem ao turno S01 e lançamentos feitos entre 14:00:00 e 22:59:59 ao turno S02.

Como calcular a data e o código do turno a que um lançamento pertence considerando esse cenário?

Comment: Me parece que um simples Join + Between resolve. Vejamos se alguém posta um exemplo.

Comment: @AntonioMano: O exemplo de saida para a linha 744 está correto? Isto é, embora a batida de ponto tenha ocorrido no dia 2016-06-25, no resultado deve constar a data de início do turno (2016-06-24) ? // A solução depende da resposta.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 2):

Veja se é isso que precisa..

```
declare @horas table
(
  serie int,
  hora datetime
)


insert into @horas values
(743,'2016-06-24 23:06:19.663'),
(744,'2016-06-25 00:05:17.852'),
(745,'2016-06-25 08:01:27.001'),
(746,'2016-06-25 16:08:01.923')


select  serie, Convert(varchar(10),hora,126),
case 
    when DATEPART(HOUR, hora) BETWEEN 5 and 14  then 'S01'
    when DATEPART(HOUR, hora) BETWEEN 14 and 22 then 'S02' 
    when DATEPART(HOUR, hora) >= 23 or DATEPART(HOUR, hora) BETWEEN 0 and 5  then 'S03' ) then 'S03'
end as codigo

from @horas
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dica: o horário final de cada turno é um intervalo aberto. No lugar de _col_ between _n1_ and _n2_ substitua por _col_ >=  _n1_ and _col_ < _n2_  //  Mas acho que as faixas horárias não devem ser _hardcoded_...

Comment: @Stormwind, verdade , fiz a correção....

Comment: @JoséDiz, não vejo um intervalo aberto, horas não são fracionadas da forma que ele esta pedindo, tem faixa de horário exatas ... DATEPART(HOUR, hora) retorna um horário exato ...  Se você precisa saber um intervalo entre 13 e às 18 horas não precisaria olhas os minutos aqui se é isso que queria dizer.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza: Observe que o autor do tópico cita textualmente que "_lançamentos feitos entre (...) 05:00:00 e 13:59:59 pertencem ao turno S01_". Ou seja, as faixas horárias que constam na tabela são intervalos abertos, à direita. Por exemplo, S01 é das 05h (inclusive) às 14h (exclusive). // Lançamento realizado às 14:02, por exemplo, deve ficar na faixa S02 mas em seu código ele cairá na faixa S01.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza: Mas a principal dificuldade está no caso 744; observou que a data retroage? Até postei pergunta ao autor, para ele confirmar se é isto mesmo.

Comment: Bastaria mudar o valor do parâmetro.. é um exemplo de como fazer... no caso é só alterar o BETWEEN 4 and 14  then ... só precisar ver a necessidade...

Answer (score 0):

Embora pareça um caso simples, há uma complicação adicional que é o fato de que o dia do lançamento deve ser ajustado para o dia anterior quando o turno cruza dia e o ponto foi batido no dia seguinte ao início do turno. Trata-se do caso 744 no exemplo postado pelo autor, em que data/horário da batida:

```
2016-06-25 00:05:17.852
```

é alterado para o dia anterior:

```
2016-06-24
```

---

Como os turnos iniciam em hora cheia (sempre ao 0 minuto), uma forma simples é transformar a tabela de turnos por faixa horária:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em uma tabela de turnos por hora, iniciando em 0h e indo até 23h:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma forma de obter a tabela de turnos por hora é a que consta no código a seguir.

```
-- código #1
declare @tbHora table (Hora int);
INSERT into @tbHora values
  (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7),
  (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), 
  (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23);

-- transforma a tabela de turno de faixa horária para hora
with 
cteTurnoFH as (
SELECT codigo, inicio, dateadd(minute, duracao, inicio) as fim
  from tbTurno
),
cteTurnoH as (
SELECT T.codigo, H.Hora
    from cteTurnoFH as T
         cross join @tbHora as H
    where 1 = case when datepart(day, T.inicio) = datepart(day, T.fim)
                        then case when H.Hora >= datepart(hour, T.inicio) 
                                       and H.Hora < datepart(hour, T.fim)
                                  then 1 else 0 end
                   else case when H.Hora >= datepart(hour, T.inicio) 
                                       or H.Hora < datepart(hour, T.fim)
                                  then 1 else 0 end
               end
)
...
```

E para exibir os lançamentos com o turno bastaria algo como

```
-- código #2
...
SELECT L.serie, cast(L.hora as date) as dia, TH.codigo
  from tbLançamento as L
       inner join cteTurnoH as TH on TH.Hora = datepart(hour, L.hora)
  order by L.serie;
```

---

Entretanto, há uma complicação adicional, que é o fato de que o dia do lançamento deve ser ajustado para o dia anterior quando o turno cruza o dia e o ponto foi batido no dia seguinte ao início do turno. Trata-se do caso 744, no exemplo postado pelo autor.

Para tratar o ajuste de dia, a CTE cteTurnoH foi ampliada, contendo coluna que indica em quais horários é necessário ajustar a data. Ao final o código ficou assim:

```
-- código #3 v2
set nocount on;

-- 
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#TurnoH', 'U') is not null
  DROP TABLE #TurnoH;
CREATE TABLE #TurnoH (Hora int primary key, codigo char(3), AjusteDia int);

--
declare @tbHora table (Hora int);
INSERT into @tbHora values
  (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7),
  (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), 
  (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23);

-- transforma a tabela de turno de faixa horária para hora
with 
cteTurnoFH as (
SELECT codigo, inicio, dateadd(minute, duracao, inicio) as fim
  from tbTurno
),
cteTurnoH as (
SELECT H.Hora, T.codigo,
       case when datepart(day, T.inicio) = datepart(day, T.fim) 
                 then 0
            else case when datepart(hour, T.inicio) <= H.Hora
                           then 0
                      else -1 
                 end
       end as AjusteDia
    from cteTurnoFH as T
         cross join @tbHora as H
    where 1 = case when datepart(day, T.inicio) = datepart(day, T.fim)
                        then case when H.Hora >= datepart(hour, T.inicio) 
                                       and H.Hora < datepart(hour, T.fim)
                                  then 1 else 0 end
                   else case when H.Hora >= datepart(hour, T.inicio) 
                                       or H.Hora < datepart(hour, T.fim)
                                  then 1 else 0 end
               end
)
INSERT into #TurnoH (Hora, codigo, AjusteDia)
  SELECT Hora, codigo, AjusteDia
    from cteTurnoH;

--
SELECT L.serie, L.hora as batida,
       cast(dateadd(day, TH.AjusteDia, L.hora) as date) as dia,
       TH.codigo
  from tbLançamento as L
       inner join #TurnoH as TH on TH.Hora = datepart(hour, L.hora);
```

E o resultado final obtido é

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso exista a possibilidade de turno iniciar em hora fracionada, o código #3 necessita ser alterado.

É provável que exista solução mais eficiente, mas foi a primeira que me veio à mente nesta madrugada.

Answer (score 0):

É possível encontrar o turno de cada lançamento fazendo um relacionamento direto entre as tabelas `lançamentos` e `turnos`.

Pode parecer uma solução mais complexa, mas ela deixa a query genérica, ou seja, se a tabela de turnos mudar, não será necessário alterar a query.

Conceitualmente, a lógica de relacionamento entre as tabelas seria a seguinte:

```
FROM lançamento
LEFT JOIN turno
     ON (lançamento.hora em D+0) between (turno.inicio em D+0) AND (turno.término em D+0)
     or (lançamento.hora em D+1) between (turno.inicio em D+0) AND (turno.término em D+1)
```

`D+0` corresponde ao dia padrão (no caso do SQLServer, o padrão é 01-01-1900) e `D+1` corresponde ao dia seguinte.

A ideia é relacionar os registros cuja `hora de lançamento em D+0` esteja entre o `início` e o `término` do turno.

Como um turno pode começar em um dia e terminar no dia seguinte, também é preciso verificar se a `hora do lançamento em D+1` está entre o `início` e o `término` do turno.

**Solução**

A solução abaixo está disponível para teste online em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b387/6

```
SELECT a.serie
      ,CAST(a.hora as DATE) as dia
      ,b.codigo
  FROM Lancamentos a
  LEFT JOIN Turnos b 
       ON CAST( CAST(a.hora as TIME) as datetime) -- hora em D+0
          BETWEEN inicio AND DATEADD( minute, duracao, inicio ) -- entre inicio AND término do turno
          OR DATEADD( day, 1, CAST( CAST( a.hora as TIME ) as datetime) ) -- hora em D+1
             BETWEEN inicio AND DATEADD( minute, duracao, inicio ) -- entre inicio AND término (no caso de término do turno em D+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei a solução sugerida pelo @fernando como *subquery* (MySql), achei mais interessante pois no caso de erros nas condições a consulta retorna erro, facilitando a avaliação.

No meu caso eu também tinha uma vigência de turnos de trabalho.

Vejam:

[image: consulta]

[image: Tab turno]

Comment: Seria interessante colocar sue SQL como texto além da imagem